# If Statement for Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

**Example**

[image: Example of Excel Spread Sheet for Vehicle Sales]

Column B is my monthly sales goal.
Columns E,F,G,H, etc are the number of sales in a given day.
When I meet my monthly goal, Column C will display 100%.

In Column D I would like to display the date asscoiated to the column of the last sale when our monthly sales goal is met.

The equation I have right now for Cell D is:

```
=IF(C2=100,D=
```

Comment: First of all let us know if you are talking about Microsoft Excel or Google's Spreadsheet document (they may look the same, but they are not). Second, your question is not clear.

Comment: I updated the question and I would like to use this for Google Spreadsheets. Thank you.

Comment: The formula is uncomplete. Is that what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(C1=100,"Day Goal Was Met","")
```